# HOW TO: Changing Dropdown Value in SugarCRM

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sugarcrm

I'm trying to change the value of a dropdown list via a click of a button, I'm using SugarCRM CE 6.5, and here's the problem I encoutered:

[image]

And here's my code below:

-- detailviewdefs.php

```
<?php
$module_name = 'UA_Quotes';
$viewdefs [$module_name] = 
array (
'DetailView' => 
array (
 'templateMeta' => 
array (
  'include' => 
   array (
    0 =>
    array (
      'file' => 
      'custom/modules/UA_Quotes/JS/clickPayment.js',
      ),
    ),
  'form' => 
  array (
    'closeFormBeforeCustomButtons' => true,
    'buttons' => 
    array (
      0 => 'EDIT',  
      1 => 'DELETE',
      2 => 
      array (
        'customCode' => '{$Monthly_Payment}',
      ),
    ),
    'footerTpl' => 'modules/UA_Quotes/tpls/DetailViewFooter.tpl',
  ),
  'maxColumns' => '2',
  'widths' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'label' => '10',
      'field' => '30',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'label' => '10',
      'field' => '30',
    ),
  ),
  'useTabs' => false,
  'tabDefs' => 
  array (
    'LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL2' => 
    array (
      'newTab' => false,
      'panelDefault' => 'expanded',
    ),
  ),
),
'panels' => 
array (
  'lbl_editview_panel2' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      0 => 'name',
      1 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'ua_contracts_ua_quotes_1_name',
      ),
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'monthlystart_c',
        'label' => 'LBL_MONTHLYSTART',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'quote_stage',
        'studio' => 'visible',
        'label' => 'LBL_QUOTE_STAGE',
      ),
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'monthlydeadline_c',
        'label' => 'LBL_MONTHLYDEADLINE',
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
),
);
?>
```

-- view.detail.php

```
<?php


require_once('include/MVC/View/views/view.detail.php');

class UA_QuotesViewDetail extends ViewDetail
{
public function __construct()
{
    parent::ViewDetail();
}

public function display()
{
    echo '<script type="text/javascript"    src="custom/modules/UA_Quotes/js/clickPayment.js"></script>';
    $groups = $this->bean->Get_Products($this->bean->id, true);
    $this->ss->assign('GROUPS', $groups);

    $this->ss->assign('NET_TOTAL', currency_format_number($this->bean->net_total_amount));
    $this->ss->assign('TOTAL', currency_format_number($this->bean->total_amount));
    $this->ss->assign('Monthly_Payment', '<input type="button" onclick="GetPayment();" value="Monthly Payment"/>');
    /*
    $this->dv->ss->assign('Monthly_Payment', '<input type="button" 
    onclick="alert(\'How to change status :(\')" value="Monthly Payment"/>');*/

    parent::display();
}
}
```

-- clickPayment.js

```
function GetPayment(){

var record = $("#record").val();
// var pathArray = window.location.href.split("=");
var fdata = { 'record':record };   
// console.log(pathArray[3]," - your Record ID");
$.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',                 
                    url: "custom/modules/UA_Quotes/js/changestatus.php?&fdata="+fdata+"",
                    data: fdata, //{recordID: pathArray[3]},
                    dataType: 'html',
                    async: false,
                    error: function(resp){},
                    success: function(resp){
                        location.reload(true);
                    }                     
                    /*  success:function(fdata){                     
                        console.log("Customer Status Change"); 
                         location.reload(true);        
                    },
                    error: function(fdata) {
                        // if error occured
                        console.log(" NA ");                     
                    }   */
                });
}
```

-- and finally, my changestatus.php

```
<?php

$myrecordID = $_POST['record'];
$focus = new UA_Quotes();
$focus->retrieve($myrecordID);
$focus->quote_stage_dom = 'Paid';

?>
```

I am very sorry for the long post of codes, I've been dealing with 'em for a couple of days now, and seems to be of no luck. :(
Any help could be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you report seems to be due to incorrect use of an entry point.

Please try registering a custom entry point in `custom/include/MVC/Controller/entry_point_registry.php` like this:

```
$entry_point_registry['ChangeStatus'] = array('file' => 'modules/UA_Quotes/entrypoint/changestatus.php' , 'auth' => '1');
```

Simply add the line in your entry point registry and if the file doesn't already exist add a file with the name at the place.

The file part in the array points to the location of your code and the auth part allows you to specify if the user needs to be authenticated or not to access the entry point.

Then call it via: `index.php?entryPoint=ChangeStatus&id=...(&to_pdf=true)`

The last parameter `&to_pdf=true` could be needed if you want the response to be json or text. Without it you get the whole html page in your answer.

You could do it without an entry point by adding a controller and then call it from your script via: index.php?module=UA_Quotes&action=changestatus

By the way you load the javascript file in metadata and view. In detailview should suffice.

Comment: Hello! Sorry for the very late reply, School caught up on me. also,  I'm kind of lost right now with all these entry-point and controllers. How could I add an controller to my CRM? or how does this entry-point in general works? and where should I put it? Apologies, I'm fairly new to Sugar itself, and after this error, I can't move on with my school project. :(

Comment: No problem. It's up to you to choose. I use controllers for standard stuff like views and for ajax access I normally create an entry point. I already described nearly everything above and updated my response a bit.

Comment: To ensure security everything in sugar runs through index.php. Modules by ?module=Accounts&action=Someaction the action is defined in a controller in Accounts module by a function action_Someaction(). Or by the use of an entry point.

Answer (score 1):

agree with first answer. may be you can try using controller for your endpoint to change file on changestatus.php
for example :

http://techs.studyhorror.com/sugarcrm-how-add-custom-actions-i-46